# does linux never end child process until the parent ends?

Tags: c, linux, fork

Please consider this code in c:

```
    int main()
    {
     pid_t cpid;
     cpid = fork();
     if (cpid == -1)
     {
            perror("fork");
            return 0;
     }
     if (cpid == 0)
     {
            printf("I'm child\n");
            _exit(0);
     }
     else
     {
            while(1)
            {
                    printf("I'm parent\n");
                    sleep(1);
            }
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

After running the code, I expect it to run child and exits it once it's done.
But when I run

```
    pgrep executable_name
```

or

```
    ps fax
```

it shows the child process id and I don't know if its just a history crap of working process or it really does not end/terminate the child process?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child will remain until its parent dies or the parent cleans it up with the `wait` system calls. (In the time between the child terminating and it being cleaned up, it is referred to as a zombie process.)

The reason is that the parent might be interested in the child's return value or final output, so the process entry stays active until that information is queried.

edit:

Example code for using the sigchld handler to immediately clean up processes when they die without blocking:

http://arsdnet.net/child.c

Be mindful of the fact that system calls (like sleep, select, or file read/writes) can be interrupted by signals. This is a normal thing you should handle anyway in unix - they fail and set errno to EINTR. When this happens, you can just try again to finish the operation. This is why my example code calls sleep twice in the parent - the first long sleep is interrupted by the child dying, then the second, shorter sleep lets us confirm the process is actually cleaned up before the parent dies.

BTW signal handlers usually shouldn't do much, they should return as soon as possible and avoid things that aren't thread safe; printfing in them is usually discouraged. I did it here just so you can watch everything as it happens.

Comment: For clarity: *only* the process table entry survives while a process is in "zombie" state; all other resources are deallocated.

Comment: ok it's a solution and thank you for giving the reason, but does not the wait blocks the parent until the state of child changes? I wanted the fork for parallelization in the first place

Comment: Yeah, wait blocks. You can also set a SIGCHLD handler and only wait when it is triggered to ensure it won't block. The signal is sent right as a child terminates. You can also just ignore it and the children will be cleaned up automatically when the parent finishes.

Comment: the reason I don't want to ignore the child to be until the life time of parent is as I know there is a limit to use multiple forks for a process and although it's limit is a high number defined in ulimit, I want to be sure that every open child would not live longer than it's use. so I would go for that SIGCHILD. a piece of question is: does clean up the forked process minus the number of used process?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "does clean up the forked process minus the number of used process?"  Specifically, since I think you're having trouble with English: the structure of the sentence only makes sense if I insert a tense marker and a plural marker -- "does cleanING up the forked process minus the number of used processES" -- but then, you are asking whether "minus the number of forked processes" is a thing that happens, and "minus" can't be used that way in my dialect of English, so I don't know what you mean. (I can guess, but I would be assuming too much to be comfortable.)

Comment: Just install the signal handler. Here's some example code: http://arsdnet.net/child.c i also edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `wait()` in the parent, otherwise the child process will never be reaped (it becomes a zombie).<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* Unless the parent itself also exits.</sub>

Comment: What about `_exit` vs `_Exit`? Shouldn't it be the latter?

Comment: @GIJoe On any system conforming to both C11 and POSIX, `_exit` and `_Exit` are exactly the same.  The C11 committee was worried (foolishly, IMNSHO) about adopting a POSIX name for a function with a textually different (but effectively identical) specification.  The differences are just because C11 describes things in different terms than POSIX does, not because the intent is different.

Comment: And if you're not interested in the status of child processes, ignore the SIGCHLD signal, and child processes will automatically be reaped.

Comment: ok it's a solution but does not the wait blocks the parent until the state of child changes? I wanted the fork for parallelization in the first place